# How can I create a userspace filesystem with FUSE without using libfuse?

Tags: linux, fuse

I've found that the FUSE userspace library and kernel interface has been ported, since its inception on Linux, to many other systems, and presents a relatively stable API with a supposedly small surface area. If I wanted to author a filesystem in userspace, and I were not on Plan 9 or Hurd, I would think that FUSE is my best choice.

However, I am not going to use libfuse. This is partially because of pragmatism; using C is hard in my language of choice (Monte). It's also because I am totally uninterested in writing C support code, and libfuse's recommended usage is incompatible with Monte philosophy. This shouldn't be a problem, since C is not magical and /dev/fuse can be opened with standard system calls.

Going to look for documentation, however, I've found none. There is no documentation that I can find for the /dev/fuse ABI/API, and no stories of others taking this same non-C-bound route. Frustrating.

Does any kind of documentation exist on how to interact in a language-agnostic way with /dev/fuse and the FUSE subsystem of the kernel? If so, could you point me to it? Thanks!

Update: There exists [go-fuse](https://github.com/hanwen/go-fuse), which is in Go, a slightly more readable language than C. However, it does not contain any ABI/API documentation either.

Update: I notice that people have voted to close this. Don't worry, there is no need for that. I have satisfied myself that the documentation that I desire does not yet exist. I will write the documentation myself, publish it, and then link to it in an accepted answer. Hopefully the next person to search for this documentation will not be disappointed.

Comment: I know C; I've been around for a while (https://www.openhub.net/accounts/MostAwesomeDude). Monte has a philosophy of safety which means that most extant C code is not usable. I'm happy to expound on this in a blog post, if there's demand.

More importantly, C is not privileged in its mechanics. I can make syscalls from any competent platform, and strace shows me that libfuse makes syscalls. I want to avoid having to reverse-engineer an open-source library.

Comment: You don't need to reverse engineer anything since you can simply read the source code and the [documentation](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/doxygen/index.html)

Comment: The documentation you've linked to does not cover the ABI of /dev/fuse, nor the magic numbers which are sprinkled throughout the source code. (It does not even cover the main source files of libfuse, only an example usage!) I understand that the source code is available; I read it for about 2-3h before asking this SO question. I'm not claiming that the lack of documentation is insurmountable; I'm claiming that I would prefer to not waste time reverse-engineering what might already be documented somewhere.

Comment: I don't get how a *standard system call* should be implemented without using C - at some level. In fact *monte* is written in python where python  is written in C. You are indeed using C.

Comment: To answer your query, a Linux syscall is made by putting things in registers and making a software interrupt; the details are at e.g. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Interfacing_with_Linux . As to Monte, I'm using Typhon, written in RPython, which is turned into a native executable. If I'm going to tie myself to a C FFI, it won't be for something like libfuse. As mentioned in my edit, I'm going to just document this thing myself and link it in an accepted answer once I'm done.

Comment: It looks like one of your stated objectives is portability. Libfuse is Linux-specific. If you reimplement libfuse in some other language, you reimplement a Linux library. Libfuse ports to other OSes are API-compatible with libfuse but use different kernel interfaces. It looks like Go-fuse works in Linux and Mac OS X/Darwin, but not in other OSes.

Answer (score 19):

(I'm not accepting this until it's complete. In the interim, edits are welcome!)

The basic outline of a FUSE session:

- `open()` is called on `/dev/fuse`. I'll call the resulting FD the **control FD**.
- `mount()` is called with the target mount point, filesystem type "fuse" for normal mode or "fuseblk" for block-device mode, and options including "fd=X" where X is the control FD.
- FUSE-specific structs are transferred on the control FD repeatedly. The general pattern of communication follows a request-response pattern, where the program `read()`s filesystem commands from the control FD and then `write()`s responses back.
- `umount()` is called with the target mount point.
- `close()` is called on the control FD.

With that all said, there's a handful of complications that one should be aware of. First, `mount()` is almost always a privileged syscall, so you'll have to be root to mount a FUSE filesystem. However, as one may have noticed, FUSE programs can generally be started as non-root! How?

There's a helper, `/bin/fusermount`, installed setuid. Usage is totally undocumented, but that's what I'm here for. Instead of `open()`ing `/dev/fuse` yourself, run `fusermount` as a subprocess, passing the target mount point as an argument, any extra mount options you like with `-o`, and (crucially) with the environment variable `_FUSE_COMMFD` exported and set to the ASCII string of an open FD, which I'll call the **comm FD**. You must create the comm FD yourself using e.g. `pipe()`. `fusermount` will call `open()` and `mount()` for you, and share the control FD back to you along the comm FD, using the `sendmsg()` trick for sharing FDs. Use `recvmsg()` to read it back.

Editorial: I really don't understand why this is structured to be so difficult. FDs are inherited by subprocesses; it would have been so much easier to `open()` the control FD in the top process and pass it down into `fusermount`. True, there's some confused deputy dangers, but `fusermount` is already installed and setuid and dangerous.

Anyway! `fusermount` will crudely daemonize and take care of calling `umount()` and `close()` to clean up once your main process exits.

Things not yet covered:

- How is non-blocking access to FUSE handled? Can the control FD just be kicked into non-blocking mode? Does it actually not block, or does it behave like an ordinary file and secretly block on access?
- The struct layouts. These can be more or less rediscovered from the C or Go source, but that's no excuse. I'll document them more seriously when I've worked up sufficient masochism.

Comment: I think you already found the answer. You might be interested in fusermount code. http://read.pudn.com/downloads96/sourcecode/unix_linux/392124/fuse-2.6.5/util/fusermount.c__.htm

Comment: @Corbin so ... did ever get the answer to the remaining questions and did you actually use this approach?

Comment: I realized that FUSE was not really what I wanted. There's a difference between "in userspace" and "unprivileged", and I wanted the latter. I haven't done any research on this since, sorry.